# BIOS ACPI bug AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT

Tags: acpi, debugging

I've been getting this persistant bug,

ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x0000000FF) is beyond end of object (length 0xF) (20200528/exoparg2-393)

I've played around with the grub config and removed quiet splash and nomodeset (which were causing other bus with my graphics driver)

Is there any kernel params that I can set to stop this bug?

My graphics are,

Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 thing that could really fix this: update your UEFI/BIOS. And if there is none you need to ask the maker of the machine to provide an update. Your hardware is giving wrong information back to the kernel about ACPI. You did not tell if there is something not working so if you do not notice anything not working you can also ignore this message. From a couple of google searches it probably does mean you can not use suspend though.

> Is there any kernel params that I can set to stop this bug?

Stop? Sure but that will disable all ACPI events; including the parts that do work. Use `acpi=off` in GRUB config.

[Dell forums](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/ACPI-BIOS-Error-bug-AE-AML-PACKAGE-LIMIT-Index-0x0000000FF-is/td-p/7557214) has an unresolved topic in this. But this also happens with HP zenbooks and a lot more machines.

Comment: ( Rinzwind from Terry Pratchet books? nice!)

Yea I tried the acpi=off and nomodeset and it did as you said it would. I just tried to fix it manually and to learn a bit (I'm new to Ubuntu), was just wondering what the ACPI bug could be for certain, but now I got my answer. Thanks to you :)

Comment: Yes big Pratchett fan here (well SF+F in general. Rinzwind is the dutch version of the name ;-) ) I have special keys on my HP open (p1-p6) that suffer from the same issue: the BIOS is giving info to Linux that Linux does not understand (in my case Linux is wrong: the bios provides 4 bytes for these keys where the kernel only expects 2 bytes).

Comment: Im up to reading Mort, it's a long and wonderful road to read I'm sure :)). I learned so much about BIOS and the kernel from this convo and migrating from windows. So much worth gained!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, but only after an Ubuntu update. I found out, that I had left an usb-stick sticking in my laptop. After I removed it the error disappeared.