# ACPRI BIOS EROR 0x000000005

Tags: kubuntu, acpi, deepin-desktop-environment

I need help with this problem:
recently I started getting this notification when starting ubuntu, and I never had this before, maybe it's because I was trying to install kubuntu/ tested deepin, out of interest

[image]

What may be the reason that I experience this issue?

Comment: Does it cause any actual problem?

Comment: We all have these. as of kernel 5.19 ACPI notices are no longer suppressed and shown during boot. Notifications shown are NOT a problem. If a system hangs it is the service not shown on screen. Basically there is 1 main cause for a crash during boot that does not show an error and just halt:  a video card driver problem. That only occurs when the driver is changed (so 1st boot or if you mess with it) and you would know about that :)  So do you have a problem with this system?

Comment: I have integrated video card, and dont change/install driver, i hope that its no provlem with my laptop

Comment: i have kernel version 5.19 but my system show this problem on screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BIOS ACPI bug AE\_AML\_PACKAGE\_LIMIT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325245/bios-acpi-bug-ae-aml-package-limit)