# ACPI Errors on Boot - Impacting Multiple Monitors & Potential BIOS Issue?

Tags: boot, kernel, bios, acpi

I see there are other topics but with no answers so I'll try and add a little more detail. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325245/bios-acpi-bug-ae-aml-package-limit) thread has a similar topic though:

**Context**

Symptoms are present when booting the laptop regardless of being plugged into a Dell D600) dock or not however where plugged in there are multiple reboots required to get the dock to behave and enable the screens and keyboard/mouse. When this boots the system is stable.

Additionally, i'm not sure if this is a red herring or not but i seem to recall this only starting after an upgrade to 22.04 from 20.x. I do see hints online about updating BIOS but it's beyond my confidence at the moment to get going and potentially brick the machine. It's perfect for what I need it for.

**Output of lsb_release -a:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**Kernel: Redacted Hostname Output of uname -a:**

```
Linux <hostinfo> 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**ACPI Errors**
**grep of dmesg for 'ACPI' for last boot** (Output of <sudo tail -50 /var/log/dmesg |grep ACPI>)

```
[   17.774079] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20221020/evregion-300)
[   17.774085] kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20221020/evregion-310)
[   17.774182] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.ECAB due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20221020/psparse-529)
[   17.774191] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.ACEL.ALRD due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20221020/psparse-529)
```

**BIOS Errors**
**Output of sudo cat /var/log/dmesg |grep BIOS**

```
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000076619fff] usable
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007661a000-0x000000007798efff] reserved
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007798f000-0x0000000077b8efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077b8f000-0x0000000077c0efff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077c0f000-0x0000000077c0ffff] usable
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077c10000-0x000000007e7fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000047d7fffff] usable
[    0.000000] kernel: efi: ACPI=0x77c0e000 ACPI 2.0=0x77c0e014 ESRT=0x76de5b98 TPMFinalLog=0x77b19000 SMBIOS=0x76de4000 MEMATTR=0x72ff2018 MOKvar=0x76dd7000 RNG=0x77b90018 TPMEventLog=0x610ad018 
[    0.000000] kernel: SMBIOS 3.1 present.
[    0.000000] kernel: DMI: HP HP ZBook Studio G5/8427, BIOS Q71 Ver. 01.09.02 11/29/2019
[    0.130014] kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.241456] kernel: ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.321007] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20221020/dsopcode-198)
[    3.687691] kernel: acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    3.832469] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000005) is beyond end of object (length 0x5) (20221020/exoparg2-393)
[    3.834091] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000005) is beyond end of object (length 0x5) (20221020/exoparg2-393)
[   12.576080] kernel: MXM: GUID detected in BIOS
[   12.596494] kernel: 0x000000000000-0x000002000000 : "BIOS"
[   14.033406] kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX11970: BIOS auto-probing.
```

**Bonus Context / Issue related to a perceived DataLeak Vulnerability (CVE-2018-3646)**

```
[   22.058560] kernel: L1TF CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See CVE-2018-3646 and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html for details.
```

Finally, I had to completely blitz the DisplayLink drivers and dkms as it completely killed my machine. It wouldn't boot into the GUI and had to re-install the core files. evdi really screwed something but seems to be stable now.

**Output of dkms status:**

```
evdi/1.13.1, 6.2.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/1.9.1: added
```

Thank you so much in advance, while this isn't troubling me too much I'd like it very much to be able to have a clean, error-free boot I enjoyed previously.

D.

Comment: the bios notices we ALL have and started with kernel 5.19. Before that these notices got suppressed and now they are not. They are benign and do not cause crashes.  It is a mismatch between what the bios should tell the kernel and what it does. It is a bios bug but there are no bios manufacturers that have fixes for these (aka. they don't care :)) Or they do care but consider a fix too risky.

Comment: "I'd like it very much to be able to have a clean, error-free boot I enjoyed previously." you never had one... just ignore the bios notifications.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I know i shouldn't laugh but i did and i guess i feel a bit stupid. Thanks for the re-assurance from a position where if you were an internet meme i'd attribute the "I've seen things, man...." slogan. 

With that said, i'm still interested in why it takes several boots to start all monitors, keyboard etc.