# Moving from kernel 5 to 6

Tags: kernel, acpi

Hi whenever I boot into the sixth version of the Linux kernel (Kubuntu flavour) I run into the following error.

[image: ACPI Error]

It however works if I boot in recovery mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BIOS ACPI bug AE\_AML\_PACKAGE\_LIMIT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325245/bios-acpi-bug-ae-aml-package-limit)

Comment: Providing your actual Kubuntu release details would be helpful; as if using a LTS release for example and the issue only occurred by moving from 5.19 to 6.2, you can switch kernel stack choice & use 5.15 which is supported for the life of *jammy* or 22.04 LTS for example. You're devoid of specific details however (*Kubuntu only mentioned & first digit of kernel detail only provided*)